# how can i create such a structure on firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

i am new to firbase platform and i don't understand how it works compared to a sql database.

my intention is to create 3 tables:

- in the first there must be the data:

**Person_ID** (primary key) (int)

rate (double)

name (String)

surname (String)

- in the second there must be

**id_spese** (primary key) (int)

amount (Double)

DateSpesa (date)

TipoSpesa (String)

*Person_ID* (foreing key) (int)

- and the third must have

**Travel_ID** (primary key) (int)

delivered (boolean)

urgent (boolean)

*Person_ID* (foreing key) (String)

KM routes (int)

anyone can explain me how can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing  because i can't understand how i can "translate" this table in firebase. I can't understand how I can "translate" the primary key and the foreign key in firebase. I already see the video on YouTube for firebase, but I can't understand at all.

Comment: So would you like the code or the database structure?

Comment: Both of them, the code and the database structure

Comment: can you help me? @AlexMamo